Is there a way to fire a function in React when user enter new URL to go to different part of the app?
I have a React application(with supabase) and I'm trying to logout user when they enter a new url.
For instance.
I want user only see /share/page. but if they are trying to enter new url like /dashboard I want the app to completely signout.
What I did try.

using useLocation from react-router-dom. wrapped in useEffect but seem like it not firing when user enter new url.
useEffect(() => {
  supabase.auth.signOut();
}, [location.pathname]);


beforeunloadeven listener not trigger as well.


    useEffect(() => {
      const handleBeforeUnload = () => {
        supabase.auth.signOut();
      };
      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
      };
    }, []);

I assume that when the new url entered and user press enter, React will perform full page reload. At the time of the reload, user already on to a new component which make all useEffect(inside the component that I expected user to see) not trigger.
Is there anyway other way to do this?

I would suggest the following user flow:

when the user is logged in: store the authentication state in a variable (a store or just a module since modules are singleton). A boolean value should be enough
in all your protected routes, check the value of the authentication state at each render. If the value is false, redirect the login page.

